# EF Core 5.0 still tracks entities even after adding AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-5.0

EF Core 5.0.1 and .NET 5

I have a query in which the entities don't need to be tracked since the result is for a HttpGet endpoint.

```
return await _context.Customers.AsNoTracking()
       .Include(x => x.Orders)
       .Include(x => x.OrderDetails)
       .Include(x => x.Payments)
       .Include(x => x.Shipments)
       .Where(x => x.Id == CustomerDto.Id)
       .ToListAsync();
```

I'm not seeing anything in the debug log indicating entities are being tracked in the above query.  But if I replace the `AsNoTracking()` with `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()`, I can see hundreds of lines similar to `Order entities are being tracked. Make sure not to log sensitive information`, `OrderDetail entities are being tracked. Make sure not to log sensitive information`, ...in the log. The documentation states EF Core uses a standalone tracking internally so not sure that's what I'm seeing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

> When you configure the query to use identity resolution with no tracking, we use a stand-alone change tracker in the background when generating query results so each instance is materialized only once.

There is a good chance I'm also dealing with the `Cartesian explosion` but not concerned about it at this point.

Also there is not much documentation on where to place the `AsNoTracking()` or `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()` in a query.  Does each table being queried need the no tracking call or one is enough for the entire query? Placing it right before ToList() like this `.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()` doesn't work - entities are still tracked.